# GEE - using ee.Image.sample to extract pixel values within a polygon

Tags: google-earth-engine, polygon, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

New to Earth Engine and trying to hack through this the best I can. Trying to sample some training data. I have 10 shape files, each containing 20 polygons spread across a large area. The problem is they were collected from an ESRI base map and all of the polys are from images from different dates.

I'm trying to pull pixel values from each poly. So for each feature in the shape file, I'm filtering the shape file to a single feature, finding the closest image to the date of the basemap it came from, counting the pixels in the poly, then trying to get the values of each pixel within the poly. The code runs, but it produces a feature collection with 0 elements even when it returns a value for pixel count.

Is there a way to do this? Also, does anyone know of a way to create a threshold for which pixels are counted, for example, to only sample them if 30% or more of a pixel is included in the poly?

Edit: included link to the shape file I'm using as well as the image collection from the data catalog.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/ee-sbegg/assets/Dune_STAINS

LS7bad = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2")

```
var dune1 = dunest.filter(ee.Filter.eq('No', 18));
var ger1 = stgers.filter(ee.Filter.eq('Id', 14));


var image = LS7bad
.filterBounds(dune1)
.filterDate('2013-05-15', '2013-05-19');

Map.addLayer(image, {bands: ['SR_B3', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B3']}, 'Dune 1 Image', true, 1.0);
Map.addLayer(dune1, {color: 'white'}, 'Stain 18', true, 1.0);
Map.addLayer(Uvs, {color: 'yellow'}, 'Uvs Border', false, 1.0);


var imagelist = ee.ImageCollection(image).toList(999);
print('List of Images', imagelist);

Map.centerObject(dune1);

var count = image.first().reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry: dune1
});

print ('Pixel Count:', count);

var pixel = image.first().sample({
  region: dune1
});
print('Pixel Values:', pixel);
```

Comment: It's not possible to reproduce this without your data. Make sure `dunest` and `LS7bad` are included in the script, and share any eventual assets you've used.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I added a link to the shape file and the image collection from the data catalog.

Comment: Your code is still incomplete and unrunnable.